# Objective-C: Best practice to call method every second

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

**THE SCENARIO** I need a method to fire off every second. I also need to be able to stop the firing of the method at any time. At the moment I am using an `NSTimer`:

**THE CODE**

```
self.controlTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updatePlayer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

**THE ISSUE** I am certain I can achieve this functionality using an `NSTimer` and call `invalidate` when I want it to stop, however I am concerned about the performance overhead of placing an `NSTimer` in a UITableViewCell.

**THE QUESTION** Does anyone know of a more light-weight alternative to calling a method every second?

Comment: nstimer is the only option we got!!! The performnace doesnt effect on how often you call you method, but what does your method have. As long as you maintain your code properly in your method, you dont need to worry about calling it every 1 second. I am saying this because, I call my method every 0.1 second and I see there is a considerable amount of lagging in the animations done. But I think if it is with 1 second , there wont be any problem

Comment: `NSTimer` is pretty much as lightweight as it can get, how many of those timers do you need? Maybe a single timer which broadcasts a `NSNotification` every second is a better solution?

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to make assumptions about the performance of code because we humans are terrible at that kind of thing. Implement it and see.

Comment: @Mr.T There are more timer sources available on OS X and iOS than just `NSTimer`. `NSTimer` is just arguably the most simple interface

Comment: I would love to hear the reason as to why someone felt it was necessary to vote down my question...

Comment: In the english language that is what we call an analogy. If you thought that I meant a computer programming object may have actual weight you must get very frustrated trying to grasp the context of anything you read online. And I feel sorry for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used `NSTimer` instances inside of `UITableViewCell` and `UICollectionViewCell` custom subclasses to do what you are doing, but I created a protocol `PLMMonitor` to provide `-startMonitoring` and `-stopMonitoring` contracts on my cells to start/stop (see: `invalidate`) any timing mechanisms.

**The Protocol**

(Obviously the protocol name prefix can be easily changed)

```
@protocol PLMMonitor <NSObject>

@required

- (void)startMonitoring;
- (void)stopMonitoring;

@end
```

**Using Cell Visibility to Control the Timers**

I could then utilize [`-[UITableViewDataSource tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:) or [`-[UICollectionViewDelegate collectionView:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegate_protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegate/collectionView:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:) to call `-startMonitoring` on the cell if it conforms to the protocol (allows for mixed cells in the `UITableView/UICollectionView`):

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([cell conformsToProtocol:@protocol(PLMMonitor)])
    {
        [(UICollectionViewCell<PLMMonitor> *)cell startMonitoring];
    }
}
```

Then I utilized the [`-[UITableViewDelegate tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:) or [`-[UICollectionViewDelegate collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell:forItemAtIndexPath:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegate_protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegate/collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell:forItemAtIndexPath:) to call `-stopMonitoring` on the cell if it conformed to the protocol (again allowing for mixed cells in the `UITableView/UICollectionView`):

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([cell conformsToProtocol:@protocol(PLMMonitor)])
    {
        [(UICollectionViewCell<PLMMonitor> *)cell stopMonitoring];
    }
}
```

**Using View Controller Visibility to Control the Timers**

You should also add code to `-viewWillAppear` and `-viewWillDisappear` to `-startMonitoring` and `-stopMonitoring` on the *visible* cells that conform to the protocol to ensure the timers get started/stopped appropriately when they are no longer visible:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear
{
    for (UICollectionViewCell *aCell in [self.collectionView visibleCells])
    {
        if ([aCell conformsToProtocol:@protocol(PLMMonitor)])
        {
            [(UICollectionViewCell<PLMMonitor> *)aCell startMonitoring];
        }
    }
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear
{
    for (UICollectionViewCell *aCell in [self.collectionView visibleCells])
    {
        if ([aCell conformsToProtocol:@protocol(PLMMonitor)])
        {
            [(UICollectionViewCell<PLMMonitor> *)aCell stopMonitoring];
        }
    }
}
```

**Performance Implications / Energy Usage of NSTimers**

One way you can reduce the impact `NSTimer` instances have on battery life, etc is the make use of their `tolerance` property which allows iOS to do [some power savings magic with them while sacrificing a strict firing interval](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSTimer/tolerance).

**Alternative Timer/Trigger Mechanisms**

- You can utilize Grand Central Dispatch's (GCD) `dispatch_after()`
  mechanism, but you will lose the ability to cancel the invocation.
- Another option is to utilize [`-[NSObject
  performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:) methods and the
  accompanying [`+[NSObject
  cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object:) 
  method to schedule a selector to be invoked and cancel an invocation
  respectively.

Comment: Thuggish your awesome.

Answer (score 2):

NSTimer is pretty lightweight.  You just need to make sure you properly handle the Cell's timer when the cell is reused.